# add a function to glibc and how to change the bind value to GLOBAL?

Tags: build, shared-libraries, glibc

For some reasons, I need to add a function to glibc. I tried to add a sample function to pthread.so:

1. add a file `glibc/nptl/my_add.c`, which return a sum of two numbers.
2. modify the `glibc/nptl/Makefile`, Add the `my_add` to "libpthread-routines"
3. make glibc and I get the pthread.so, but the func's bind value is LOCAL. **How to change the bind value form LOCAL to GLOBAL?**

```
$ readelf build/nptl/pthread.so.0 -s | grep "my_add"
   326: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS my_add.c
   458: 0000000000013550     4 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   14 __my_add
   510: 0000000000013550     4 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   14 my_add@@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

I think that maybe I am ought to modify the gcc flags in Makefile, but I don't know how to do it. The glibc is complicated for me， but I hava to slove it.

please help me, thanks!

my_add.c

```
#include "pthreadP.h"
#include <shlib-compat.h>


int __my_add (int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
versioned_symbol (libpthread, __my_add, my_add, GLIBC_2_1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but the func's bind value is LOCAL.

This is because GLIBC build process tightly controls the set of external symbols (so no undesirable or internal-only symbols are exported).

You must add `my_add` function to `nptl/Versions` file.

Comment: @noobcjl If an answer helped you, you are supposed to upvote it. If it resolved your problem, you should accept the answer.